# Conditional observables that call other observables?

Tags: rxjs

I'm fetching an object (roster) from a store (Akita), and based on whether that object exists, I'm either requesting one from the server (my `if`) and passing it along OR (my `else`) taking the one I receive, fetching another object (manifest), doing a synchronous operation on the both of them, and then passing the result along.

I've tried just returning the objects, as well as returning `of(the object)` and the error is the same: `Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Roster>'. Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Roster'`

```js
selectRoster(slug: string): Observable < Roster > {
    
    const roster$ = this.selectEntity(slug).pipe(
        map((roster: Roster) => {
            if (!roster) {
                this.rosterService.loadRoster(slug).pipe(
                    map((load: Roster) => {
                        return load
                    })
                );
            } else {
                this.manifestQuery.selectEntity(roster.manifest.manifest_slug).pipe(
                    map((manifest: Manifest) => {
                        return this.rosterProcess.composeRegistry(roster, manifest)
                    })
                );
            }
        })
    )   
    return roster$
}
```

I had thought that returning from within the `if/else` would work, based on my research, but it's complaining.

Comment: What does `rosterProcess.composeRegistry()` return?

Comment: It seems you are not returning anything from `map((roster: Roster) => {....`. So this is maybe why Typescript is telling you that `roster$` is an `observable` of `void`.